# each android device had it's own default theme for applications?

Tags: android

I run my applcation in Motorola,HTC devices and each group of devices my application dialog box,Text box appearance is different.Why this will happend?Is device to device any specific theme applied on my application?Iam n't used any custom theme for my application.

how to persist my application look and feel in all devices.I know little bit, by using our own theme we can persist.but, I don't have time to develope my own theme.I want to take the source of one device default theme and utilise that one in my application.So that I think i can see the application same in all devices.how to get the theme from one device,if my above sentence correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right every manufacturer applies some styling to their user interface. 
There are some places where this is fine for example dialog boxes should look the same in every application on the device. If a dialog box would look completely different then all the other dialogs this would confuse the user.

Some things are annoying for example the motorola motoblur phones use a black background image for spinners and normal andoroid phones use a grey one.

Have a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874310/my-spinner-widgets-look-different-on-different-devices-how-can-i-define-a-own-sp) regarding this problem. It is a solution for a small part of your problem but maybe it shows you how to search for the other images and themes that you need to copy.